# Show record data in the last 1 hour in sybase ASA11

Tags: sql, datetime, where-clause, sybase, sybase-asa

```
select * from Trx   
where 
RequestTimestamp BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) AND DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE())
```

I have this sql code from sybase ASA11, hoping to show data in last 1 hour, but it just shows today's record from 00:00:00.000 AM till now(). What is wrong with my script, so it can show all of record from 1 last hour to now(). Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```
where requestTimestamp >= dateadd(hour, -1, getdate())
```

If you have `requestTimestamp` in the future, then an upper bound is also needed:

```
where requestTimestamp between dateadd(hour, -1, getdate()) and getdate();
```

Comment: wait, you're not using now()?

Comment: @ilhamsetiawan: `now()` and `getdate()` are synonyms.

Comment: what's the difference "If you have requestTimestamp in the future" (the second line)? coz I just run the script and have the same result with the first line/code

Comment: @ilhamsetiawan: so it means you don't have `requestTimestamp`s that are greater than `getdate()`.

Comment: I'm gonna use for an Event that run every one hour, I guess I'm using the first line, right?